# JavaScript function not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a link in a new tab on click of a link , Below is the code for reference. This code works fine in Google chrome but it is not working in IE 9 . Is there way to make it work on IE 9 ?

```
<html>  
    <a href="#" class="test2" id="test" onclick="openNewBackgroundTab('https://google.co.in/')">click Me</a>

    <script>
        function openNewBackgroundTab(url){
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = url;

            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName("test2")[0].click();
    </script> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.open`? You're in an `onclick` event so it should work fine without popup blockers worrying.

Comment: what about <a href="#" target="_blank">Text</a>?

Comment: Well @Olli1511 if it's an `<a>` tag why not just give it the URL for its "href" and a "target"?  Then no JavaScript is needed at all!

Comment: Note that you cannot force a browser to open a new tab (or window) in any particular way - that's under user control.

Comment: Its because i want to open the URL in a  new tab instead of a new window, target="_blank" will open the URL in a new window

Comment: @Pointy My comment was only a comment not a solution ;) but I agree with you, no javascript needed. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: I think that's a setting of your browser, you can't change it as @Pointy already mentioned. (only as user, not as developer)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I got your qestion wrong, but if you only want to open a link in a new tab, what about this solution?

```
<a href="#" class="test2" id="test" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');" >click Me</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="test2" id="test" target="_blank">click Me</a>
```

Comment: I want a new tab , your code will open the link in a new window

Comment: @user3223016 you cannot force browsers to open in tabs or windows. That is completely up to the user configuration of the browser and/or the decisions of the browser implementors.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd option seems to be the simplest and best way.